# CHM reader for Linux

Tags: linux, ebooks

I would like to have a CHM reader for reading some ebooks I have in that format. Please meet the following requirements:

1. The files I have are quite big like 200 to 300 MB. The reader suggested must load them quickly and must not crash during navigation
2. Ability to search
3. Ability to copy from text
4. Ability to highlight or bookmark text

I use Linux. I would like FOSS.

Comment: @Davidenko That link is dead now (error 404)